# wkhtmltopdf 0.12.4 - Images not converted to pdf in kubernetes devops server in scala

Tags: scala, wkhtmltopdf

I am using devops server, In this, I need to change the HTML to pdf conversion by using Scala. For this, I have used wkhtmltopdf 0.12.4 package. HTML everything was converted well except the images. I have used two formats for image generation.

```
 <img src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/5.png" alt="image_url_" 01 " width=400px style="padding:1%;border:0px;margin:0px;float:left ">

 <div style="background-image: url(&quot;https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/5.png&quot;); height: 73px; padding-top: 30px; text-align: center; width: 75px; color: white;box-sizing: border-box;line-height: 13px; background-repeat: no-repeat; list-style-type:
    none; ">62</div>
```

**But the same was working fine in Ubuntu machine**

am using my s3 configurations like

```
s3.https = false
```

but my image URLs are like `https://` is this any cause for converting images to pdf